# How to best to describe a user preference option to play all videos in succession?

Tags: labels, options, user-preferences

I've created a program that contains eight chapters (they are actually videos) and I have a user preference that when checked will play all eight chapters in succession one right after the other.

**For Example:**

- When Chapter 1 finishes Chapter 2 starts
- When Chapter 2 finished Chapter 3 starts
- so on and so forth...
- When Chapter 8 finishes it starts over again with Chapter 1

I can't seem to come up with user friendly phrase to describe this option. Here are some of the phrases I came up with...

Loop Presentation
Play Continuously
Play Chapters in Succession

All of these seem to miss the mark as far as conveying the meaning in a user friendly way. What do you think would be a good phrase to use for this user preference option?

Comment: In music players, it's called repeat all. Of the 3 you mention, I think Loop Presentation is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious to understand why you would play the chapters in a loop.

For me the language needs to be as simple as possible.

Some options:

Play all videos 
Play all chapters
**or just** 
Play all

Answer (score 0):

If it's starting over, I agree with @user1261104 to call it "Repeat all". I've seen it without the start-over-feature (depends on use case, clearly) in Lynda.com, and I think it was called "Play Continuously" (can't verify right now).